# customize kaminari pagination template

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, kaminari

I'm having difficulty customizing the default kaminari template.

I've used the generator to create kaminari template files. In kaminari/paginator.html.haml:

```
= paginator.render do
  %nav.pagination
```

All I want to do is access the actionview helpers within this, like link_to, or render. I've searched the source code and I can't find any incline of the helper being passed to this render method.

Essentially, being able to do this:

```
= paginator.render do
  %nav.pagination
    = render :partial => 'custom links'
    = link_to "custom link", custom_path
```

..would solve my problems.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I didn't get a satisfactory answer, and so I'll submit my own solution.

Helpers cannot be used in the `paginator.render` block.

So, first I generate kaminari custom template files:

```
rails g kaminari:views default -e haml
```

Create a new file kaminari/custom.html.haml with the contents:

```
#pagination
  = paginate custom
  = render :partial => "kaminari/custom_view_file"
```

Replace kaminari paginator helper (`paginate @results`) in your view file with:

```
= render :partial => "kaminari/custom", :object => @results
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do something like this:

```
# /app/views/kaminari/_paginator.html.erb

= paginator.render do
  %nav.pagination
    = render :partial => 'shared/custom'
    = link_to "custom link", custom_path
```

Basically, you need to provide the full path of the partial as it probably does not reside in the same directory.

EDIT:

I think Kaminari does not import rails view helpers in the paginate.render block in _paginator.html.erb.
To customize the output generated by paginator, you should instead
1. customize the _next_page.erb.html and so on where you can use rails helpers. I don't know why it is so though.
2. If you want to display some common html as a part of paginator, I suggest you put it in layout instead. Paginator is about navigation of pages.

For example, this is the _prev_page.html.erb:

```
<span class="prev">
  <%= link_to "google", "www.google.com" %>
  <%# link_to_unless current_page.first?, raw(t 'views.pagination.previous'), url, :rel => 'prev', :remote => remote %>
</span>
```

I just commented out the old code and used a custom link.

Comment: You can't. ActionView helpers are not within scope. This is the _first_ thing I tried. Thanks though.

Comment: You can include them -  include ActionView::Helpers

Comment: Sorry, do you mean hack kaminari to include them?

Comment: What errors do you get? Coming to think of it, your paginator.render block should evaluate to a haml string I think. So, you may need to user render_to_string (http://rails.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Base.html#M000465)

Comment: I'm sorry, have you ever used Kaminari custom templates? render, render_to_string, link_to, none of the helpers are within scope of kaminaris paginator.render method.

Comment: No, I have not used custom templates, just plain Kaminari. I am looking at the https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari_themes and I am surprised that his theme uses link_to and other helpers, but yours gives error. Hence the question - what exact errors do you get?

Comment: That the link_to is not a recognized method. Like I say, the view helpers are not within scope. He isn't using link_to at all in the paginator.render method..might be in the custom templates, but that is a different story. He uses _tag to render those templates, as in - the render method is also not within scope.

Comment: You are right. I tried it by generating a custom view. It does not import Rails helpers automatically. I tried to use the full module name (ActionController::Base.helpers.link_to), but it gives error because it cannot understand url_for call inside link_to method. Sorry, cannot help you.

Comment: How can i add two span classes in kaminari default files and access the span according to my choice in views?

Answer (score 1):

Just met the same problem.
My solution:

```
= paginator.render do
  %nav.pagination
    = render :partial => 'custom links'
    = @template.link_to "custom link", custom_path
```

As partial rendering occurs in scope of Paginator, there is possibility to use its instance variable, pointing to template (see https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari/blob/master/lib/kaminari/helpers/paginator.rb)

Little hacky, but works.