# Need to exclude pre and next buttons from kaminari pagination

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, kaminari

I want to change kaminari pagination paginate helper format like

First,Prev - current page - Next,Last

Because its breaking my design with unwanted numbers. 
 I tried with all other helpers but no success.

Is there any way? Please let me know your thoughts.

Answer (score 2):

Here's my thoughts. You need to go to the [Kaminari GitHub page](https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari#customizing-the-pagination-helper). That link leads to section about generating Kaminari partials, so you can edit them just like you want. Right from that page:

```
rails g kaminari:views default -e haml
```

Where `haml` is your template engine. You can replace it by `erb`, `slim` (depending on what you prefer to use).

***Update***. Here's a [related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10821262/customize-kaminari-pagination-template) question about customizing Kaminari templates.

Comment: Thanks for your swift reply. But I want this change in one place not whole application.

Comment: You can use these templates and create your own. Then you can render it instead of original one.

Comment: Yes, I changed template but need to render it one place through helper like => paginate @users, :remote => true

Comment: got it -> = render :partial => "kaminari/custom", :object => @results

Comment: tried like that but getting error like undefined local variable or method `paginator'

Comment: Any Idea? How to render after customized template in to our paginate helper.   paginate @users, :remote => true

Comment: Updated my answer. You should find details by the link.

Answer (score 2):

Use Kaminari's themes

```
<%= paginate @users, :theme => 'my_custom_theme' %>
```

you need custom kaminari view files in

```
app/views/kaminari/my_custom_theme
```

And another simpler solution, what happen if you do this?

```
<%= paginate @users, :window => 0 %>
```

You can customize it a little more using CSS, each part of the pagination widget has some class or id, you can hide/show/modify them

Answer (score 0):

```
[vidur@centos7-demo tukaweb]$ rails g kaminari:views default -e erb
Running via Spring preloader in process 25960
      create  app/views/kaminari/_first_page.html.erb
      create  app/views/kaminari/_gap.html.erb
      create  app/views/kaminari/_last_page.html.erb
      create  app/views/kaminari/_next_page.html.erb
      create  app/views/kaminari/_page.html.erb
      create  app/views/kaminari/_paginator.html.erb
  create  app/views/kaminari/_prev_page.html.erb
```

in the view:

```
   <%= paginate @data %>
```